# How can I get application by process

Tags: c#, process, cross-platform

it's impossible to get app info(name, maybe other) by `Process` class? I know i can get **.exe** file name, but i want get app name. It is desirable that the solution be cross-platform?

Example:
[image]

I can get MainWindowTitle 'Новая вкладка - Google Chrome', but i need application name like in task manager (Google Chrome). I can parse title, but this is not a universal way.

Comment: why would you do that? Most executables simply aren't currently running, so there's no process attached to that exe. You can however get all running processes using `Process.GetProcesses()` and from there get their names.

Comment: I probably didn't express myself correctly, I updated the question.

Comment: I suspect what you'll need to do is find the EXE, then open it up and look at its file properties

Comment: I still don't get it. An exe-file is not a process. Only when you **run** that executable, you have a process. So unless your exe is running- there literally is no process and thus no name for that process. How did you get the above image?

Comment: Try `process.MainModule?.FileVersionInfo?.FileDescription`.

Comment: `FileVersionInfo` can get `FileDescription`, it almost always matches the application. This works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the descrition of the executable file for a running process, you can use

```
string GetProcessDescription(Process process)
{
      try
      {
        return process.MainModule?.FileVersionInfo?.FileDescription;
      }
      catch
      {
        return null;
      }
}
```

The exception handler is necessary because you might not have the permission to access the information, or the process might not have a file module at all.